# the sample method of Spark RDD does not work as expected

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am trying with the "sample" method of RDD  on Spark 1.6.1

```
scala>val nu = sc.parallelize(1 to 10)
scala>val sp =  nu.sample(true,0.2)
scala>sp.collect.foreach(println(_))
```

3
8

```
scala>val sp2 = nu.sample(true, 0.2)
scala>sp2.collect.foreach(println(_))
```

2
4
7
8
10

I cannot understand why sp2 contains 2,4,7,8,10.
I think there should be only two numbers printed.
Is there anything wrong?

Comment: cannot reproduce this, can you specify your Spark version?

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on the previous answer: in the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) (scroll down to `sample`) it is mentioned (emphasis mine):

> fraction: **expected** size of the sample as a fraction of this RDD's size without replacement: probability that each element is chosen; fraction must be [0, 1] with replacement: **expected** number of times each element is chosen; fraction must be >= 0

'Expected' can have several meanings depending on the context, but one meaning it certainly does not have is 'exact', hence the varying exact number of the sample size.

If you want absolutely fixed sample sizes, you may use the `takeSample` method, the downside being that it returns an array (i.e. not an RDD), which must fit in your main memory:

```scala
val nu = sc.parallelize(1 to 10)
/** set seed for reproducibility */
val sp1 = nu.takeSample(true, 2, 182453) 
sp1: Array[Int] = Array(7, 2)

val sp2 = nu.takeSample(true, 2)
sp2: Array[Int] = Array(2, 10)

val sp3 = nu.takeSample(true, 2)
sp2: Array[Int] = Array(4, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fraction does not mean give me this number of element *exactly*. It says give me this number of elements *on average* so you will have different numbers of elements if you run several time.

Answer (score -1):

**sample** method on RDD,

> Return a sampled subset of this RDD.

The return type is **undocumented**, so it could be anything from your master RDD.